# How can I extract data from a recordset in VBA using a non-literal string?

Tags: sql, vba

By my understanding, if I want to extract data from a recordset this code is sufficient: `strFirstName = rstEmployees!FirstName`where rstEmployees is the recordset and FirstName is the name of a column. However, I would like to know how I can do this more abstractly, and use a string variable name instead of FirstName such that I could change this variable and get different results.

Comment: You want to build the name of the field? - `rstEmployees.Fields("FirstName" & 23)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Fields* collection and pass your variable:

```
= rstEmployees.Fields(strFirstName).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question correctly, you can use the `Fields` property of the `Recordset` with the fieldname or array index as the key. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/fields-collection-ado?view=sql-server-ver15

Sample code:

```vb
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'A sample recordset.
With rs.Fields
    .Append "id", adInteger
    .Append "first_name", adVarChar, 50
    .Append "last_name", adVarChar, 50
End With

rs.Open
rs.AddNew Array("id", "first_name", "last_name"), Array(1, "John", "Doe")

'Accessing the fields.
Debug.Print "Literal: " & rs!first_name
Debug.Print "String: " & rs.Fields("first_name").Value
Debug.Print "Abbr. code: " & rs("first_name")

rs.Close
```